# Prevent dex core-library error for xalan with gradle 2.0.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dex, xalan

I try to get xalan 2.7.2 working with Android using gradle 2.0.0 (gradle wrapper 2.10)

I have added xalan 2.7.2 and also tagsoup 1.2.1 to my gradle dependencies in order to get a valid SAX2DOM document from sloppy HTML sources

But: If I run the gradle build for this setup, I immediately get an error:

> ```
> Ill advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
> when not building a core library.
> This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
> in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
> Eclipse).
> [...]
> If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
> appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
> distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
> the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
> ```

So I tried to do this, but figured out during the process of implementing the `--core-library` option, that it is only possible with gradle 1.3.0 (and gradle wrapper 2.2)

Then it all worked with those options in the application's build.gradle:

```
dexOptions {
   preDexLibraries = false
}

project.tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex) {
   additionalParameters = ['--core-library']
}
```

I always thought and hoped that there would be another and much better solution for this.

But now the time has come that I'd really like to get rid of this overhead because I'd like to take advantage of the new Android Studio 2.0 features like Instant Run, which can only be used with gradle 2.0.0

So my question: What is the right way to use a library like xalan (SAX2DOM) in Android together with the latest version of gradle?

EDIT: I found out that it's more about xalan than tagsoup (because xalan seems to have a dependency to javax.xml.XMLConstants), so I edited the question accordingly

EDIT2: The root cause seems to be the transitive dependency from xalan via xalan-serializer to xml-apis. This is what `gradlew app:dependencies` is showing:

```
+--- xalan:xalan:2.7.2
|    \--- xalan:serializer:2.7.2
|         \--- xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.04
```

The xml-apis-1.3.04.jar actually contains the javax.xml.* classes

The current question is: How can I included those classes into my project avoiding the core-library issue for current gradle versions?

EDIT3: I cannot seem to get this working.

After repackaging the xml-apis, xalan-serializer and xalan jars using jarjar I put the resulting jar files into my project's libs folder (which I also included in my gradle dependencies for compile).

Xalan, though, has another *optional* dependency to xercesImpl, which is being used during runtime, so I had to add it as a dependency.

But the jar seems to be quite old, so I get ParseErrors from it during the gradle build.

Other sources suggest to recompile xerces from sources, but I only get `bad class file magic (cafebabe)` exceptions after including the rebuilt xerces jar ....

I'm giving up for now

Answer (score 0):

You *really* don't want to use the --core-library option. Per the warning: "which is only appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
distribution, as opposed to compiling an application". You're not building a "full virtual machine distribution", you're compiling an application.

I think the real solution here is to either

1. Figure out what `java.*`/`javax.*` classes are being compiled into your application and prevent them from being compiled in

OR

2. If you really do need those classes compiled into your application, use something like jarjar to rename them to something other than `java.*`/`javax.*`

Comment: May I ask why? I am using libs like joda-time, xalan, jackson-databind and tagsoup. How can I find out which of those libraries are using java*:* classes?

Comment: Did you actually read the full warning that dx gave? :) It goes to great lengths to tell you why you shouldn't be using --core-library when building an application. It even gives you info about how to properly handle this situation, which basically matches the suggestions I provided in my answer.

Comment: Not just using java.* classes, but actually including them as part of the jar. Just find the actual jar files on the filesystem and see what classes are in them.

Comment: It might be a transitive dependency, I cannot find any jar in my project having java.* or javax.* classes

Comment: Please see `EDIT2` of my question ... I hope you can help me there. It could be of great benefit also for many other users, guessing from the amount of questions regarding this issue

Comment: See latest `EDIT3`

Answer (score 0):

The solution (at least most of it) is amazingly easy and was mentioned in this Android blog post: http://jmlinnik.blogspot.de/2015/07/android-studio-android-ill-advised-or.html

```
compile ('xalan:xalan:2.7.2') {
    exclude group: 'xml-apis'
}
```

Obviously the classes used from xml-apis are already included in Android, so it is not necessary (and even wrong) to include them with this transitive dependency.

BUT: Building the app with gradle 1.5.0, after removing the dex options mentioned above, produces a lot of warnings like

> Warning:Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
> (org.apache.xml.serializer.SecuritySupport$1) that doesn't come with
> an associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably
> produced by a compiler that did not target the modern .class file
> format. The recommended solution is to recompile the class from
> source, using an up-to-date compiler and without specifying any
> "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring this warning is
> that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly indicate
> that it is *not* an inner class.

With gradle 2.0.0 those warnings turned into errors, but the apk is still building correctly

> Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner
> class (org.apache.xpath.functions.SecuritySupport$8) that
> doesn't come with an associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This
> class was probably produced by a compiler that did not target
> the modern .class file format. The recommended solution is to
> recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
> and without specifying any "-target" type options. The
> consequence of ignoring this warning is that reflective
> operations on this class will incorrectly indicate that it is
> *not* an inner class.
>
> :app:validateDebugSigning
>
> :app:packageDebug
>
> :app:zipalignDebug
>
> :app:fullDebugBuildInfoGenerator
>
> :app:assembleDebug
>
> Information:BUILD SUCCESSFUL

This seems to be a bug which I hope will be fixed soon.

Comment: Those warnings are not a bug. The problem is likely the xalan classes target a very old java version (likely < 1.5). However, the warnings are harmless and shouldn't affect anything.

Comment: I mentioned a bug because there used to be warnings that are now marked as ERRORs which don't affect the build process? This seems to be a bug because every error usually makes the build process fail